# Pressing play after returning to App SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

> APP DELEGATE CRASHING PROBLEM

I'm a very beginner at programming and, while developing my app, an unsolutionable problem showed up. I've tried to pause the game when the user leaves the app itself and, when the return is wanted, the game is pause since de home button is pressed. My difficulty is, when the user leaves the app with the game unpaused and come back, it works perfectly, but when the user pauses the game and leave, Xcode shows me an error message: "*Thread 1: signal SIGARBT*" and the game crashes. If you take a peek on my game, I'd be very pleased

> CODE ITSELF

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

    //pause when leaving app
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("pauseState"), name: "pauseState", object: nil)
}
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var gameLayer = SKNode()
var pauseLayer = SKNode()

var gameStarted = Bool()

var pauseButton = SKSpriteNode()
var playButton = SKSpriteNode()

func setupPauseButton(){

    //Pause
    pauseButton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "pause")
    pauseButton.setScale(0.25)
    pauseButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 10, y: self.frame.height / 1.5)
    //pauseButton.zPosition = 3
}
func setupPlayButton(){

    //Play
    playButton = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "play")
    playButton.setScale(0.15)
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 10, y: self.frame.height / 1.5)
    //playButton.zPosition = 3
}

//layers
func createGameLayer(){

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    setupPauseButton()
    gameLayer.addChild(pauseButton) //add pauseButton to gameLayer
    pauseButton.hidden = true
}
func createPauseLayer(){

    //Play
    setupPlayButton()
    pauseLayer.addChild(playButton) //add playButton to pauseLayer
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */

    //pause when coming back
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("pauseState"), name: "pauseState", object: nil)

    self.addChild(gameLayer)

    createGameLayer()
    createPauseLayer()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
/* Called when a touch begins */

    //run only if game is running
    if gameLayer.paused == false{

        //pauseButton shows when starting to play
        pauseButton.hidden = false
    }

    //when touch buttons/screen
    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node == pauseButton{
            pauseState()
        }

        else if node == playButton{
            playState()
        }

        else{

            if gameStarted == false{  //game didn't start yet

                gameStarted = true

                Character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true //start falling when touch the screen

                //first jump
                Character.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
                Character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 15))
                }
            }
            else{

                //jump
                Character.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
                Character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 15))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//states
func pauseState(){

    pauseButton.hidden = true //hide pauseButton
    self.physicsWorld.speed = 0 //pause physics (character, etc)
    gameLayer.paused = true //pause gameLayer

    self.addChild(pauseLayer) //add pauseLayer
}
func playState(){

    pauseLayer.removeFromParent() //remove pauseLayer

    gameLayer.paused = false //unpause gameLayer
    self.physicsWorld.speed = 1 //unpause physics (character, etc)
    pauseButton.hidden = false //show pauseButton
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

}
```

Comment: Learn to debug a crash by visiting http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things I noticed with your code

1) As of swift 2.2 apple finally changed the selector methods away from strings. So in your gameScene change the observer to this.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene.pauseState), name: "pauseState", object: nil)
```

https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-selector-syntax-sugar-81c8a8b10df3#.kncj5thdh

2) In your app delegate you are adding another observer which doesnt make sense. You want to post the notification to the observer you have in GameScene.

Change it to this

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("pauseState", object: nil)
```

3) Not sure you are doing this but its always recommended to remove any NSNotification observers when you leave a scene. Call this line

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

when you transition to a new scene or in GameScenes "WillMoveFromView" method

Also its a good idea if you follow apples naming conventions. Only classes, structs, enums and protocols should start with capital letters. This makes your code more readable for yourself and on SO (your code is marked blue but shouldn't)

Hope this helps.